# Table with multiple sub table in .rdlc report in C#

Tags: c#, rdlc

I am working on window application in Visual Studio (C#). I want to create a dynamic report in c# using `.rdlc` report. And i want to generate table with multiple sub tables in it as per requirement or filter in report (something like in grid view). I attached a sample image. I want to generate report like as report in attached image. Please provide me some suggestion how can I do this.

[Report Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Tv5z.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this either by grouping your data or with subreports. I would recommend grouping.
Here are two MSDN links that can help you:

[Create a Stepped Report](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220467.aspx)

[Add a Subreport and Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220581.aspx)